# Google docs spreadsheet: How to list which column contains biggest number in a row, second biggest, etc?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet, formulas

Let's say I have a google docs spreadsheet with multiple columns where each team has a number of points:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------++-------------+--------+--------+
| TEAM A | TEAM B | TEAM C | TEAM D || Game Winner | 2nd    | 3rd    |
+--------+--------+--------+--------++-------------+--------+--------+
| 23     | 11     | 51     | 34     || TEAM C      | TEAM D | TEAM A |
| 47     | 80     | 53     | 71     || TEAM B      | TEAM D | TEAM C |
| 72     | 36     | 12     | 22     || TEAM A      | TEAM B | TEAM D |
+--------+--------+--------+--------++-------------+--------+--------+
```

How do I write a formula that automatically generates the "Game Winner" column for each row, based off the number of points? Additionally, how do I generate 2nd place, 3rd place, etc?

For my actual spreadsheet, I have 7 teams, so a massive "if" statement is... unwieldy. I'm not sure if there's a formula I can use for this or not.

Just an answer that is like "check out the documentation for this formula" would be great. I'm a CS major so if you point me towards a built-in function that'd be fine; I'm just not too familiar with excel functions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the TEAM names are on the first row (A1, B1, etc), to get the winning team for eache row you can use this formula:

```
=offset(A1;0;match(large(A2:D2;1);A2:D2;0)-1)
```

In order to get the second and third place you should change de "1" in the large formula for a 2 or a 3 like this:

```
=offset(A1;0;match(large(A2:D2;2);A2:D2;0)-1)
=offset(A1;0;match(large(A2:D2;3);A2:D2;0)-1)
```

Hope this answer your question. Have a great day!

**EDIT:**
For more information about this formula you can check this link: 
[OFFSET Formula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en)

Comment: Great answer, (but) have a tab for tied scores!

Comment: I´m sorry I can´t help you with that